# angularjs http service unit testing

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I am trying to test a simple service for learning purposes..However; I can't figure out how it must be done:

service:

```
.factory('myService', function($http) {
  var myService = {
    async: function() {
      var promise = $http.get('test.json').then(function (response)
{
        return response.data;
      });
      return promise;
    }
  };
  return myService;
});
```

controller:

```
myService.async().then(function(d) {
    $scope.data = d;
    $scope.e = $scope.data.txt;
  });
```

test:

```
'use strict';
describe("myService", function(){

    beforeEach(module("testingExpApp"));

    var myService,
        $httpBackend;

    beforeEach(inject(function(myService, _$httpBackend_){
        myService = myService;
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    }));

    describe("get", function(){

        it('should return test.json data', function () {
        var url = "../mock/test.json";
        var x = $httpBackend.expectGET(url).respond(200, 'txt from json');

         // flush response
        $httpBackend.flush();
        expect(x).toBe('txt from json');

        });

    });

});
```

I get 'no pending request to flush!'

I just want to test that myservice.get() get the test.json file data..I have tried everything but can't get it working..

Any tips?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: try removing the $httpBackend.flush() method and tell me what you get.

Comment: expected object <<respond: Function >> to be 'txt from json'

Comment: You may want to wrap it in a method and use Jasmine spys. spyOn(UserService, 'getCurrentUser').and.returnValue({});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was missing is to call service function

it had to be:

```
it('should return test.json data', function () {
    var url = "../../mock/test.json";
    $httpBackend.expectGET(url).respond(200, 'data from test.json');

    //Execute service func here..
    myServiceFunc.async().then(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        expect(result).toEqual('data from test.json');
    });
    $httpBackend.flush();          
    });
```